# Images using google sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets

How can i get image from sheet?
i have this code:

```
import pprint
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
response = build('sheets', 'v4', http=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/creds/sacc1.json", ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']).authorize(httplib2.Http())).spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId="17sm8mLGok1WzADZJxaeTCEFaiXj4CFpZk0cIQPYIu5Y", ranges="Под-системы!I14:I14", includeGridData = True).execute()
pprint.pprint(response['sheets'][0]['data'][0]['rowData'][0]['values'])
```

but response does not contain any images

Answer (score 0):

If the image is inserted or pasted directly into the spreadsheet, the image cannot be retrieved since Image types are not included in the response `values[]` as you can check in the [Google Sheets Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange).

However, if the image is being inserted with the `=IMAGE("url.jpeg")` formula, then you can retrieve that `url` using the argument `valueRenderOption="FORMULA"`, which will return `'=IMAGE("url.jpeg")'`  as a string and you could easily get the `url.jpeg` out of it.

An example:

```py
def read(spreadsheet_id, range_, value_render_option: str = "FORMATTED_VALUE"):
    gsheets = build_service()
    result = (
        gsheets.spreadsheets()
        .values()
        .get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
            range=range_,
            valueRenderOption=value_render_option,
        )
        .execute()
    )
    return result

read("17sm8mLGok1WzADZJxaeTCEFaiXj4CFpZk0cIQPYIu5Y", "Под-системы!I14:I14", "FORMULA")
```

and a example of what you would get back is:

```
{'range': 'Под-системы!I14:I14', 'majorDimension': 'ROWS', 'values': [['=IMAGE("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A-Cat.jpg")']]}
```